# Getting printer info on a remote computer (per user profile)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to list printers attached to user profiles on remote computers using powershell. 
The following part of my code doesn't work:

```cs
$logonInfo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "$computer" -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem" |
             select -ExpandProperty Username 
$userSID = Get-ADUser -Server $b.ADServer -Filter {samaccountname -eq "$logonInfo"} |
           select -ExpandProperty SID |
           select -ExpandProperty value
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("users", "$computer")
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("$userSID\Printers\")
$userprinters = $RegKey.GetValue("connections")
```

What does work is:

- getting computers from AD
- getting logged in users using get-wmiobject
- getting SIDs from usernames

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/876642/get-network-printers-from-a-remote-computer) should help.

Comment: Jrider hit it on the head. I'm not certain you can isolate it to printer per user. But I don't see why not either.